# Differences between importing libs in angular.json and component

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to import jQuery in my Angular 7 application and I noticed that where are two ways to do this.

1. Importing the **jquery.min.js** file into the `scripts` property of **angular.json**
2. Importing jQuery from ts code (for example in main.ts or a module) using `import 'jquery';`

What is the difference between these approaches?

Answer (score 2):

1. Makes the script global (like placing a script tag in index.html)
2. Makes use of modules, which avoids global scope pollution, and lets tools like Webpack optimise the bundling process, e.g. by “tree-shaking”.

Answer (score 2):

First I must say that mixing JQuery with angular is in most cases **a bad idea**, So I hope You have a good reason for it. About your question

When importing a file using `scripts` property of **angular.json**, You do exactly that - importing the entire file and running it's code. On angular, the will be done prior to the execution of your angular app code.

On the other hand, when importing a module (after installing it using a package manager like **npm**), You can import only the modules you need, which usually means less code in being executed by the browser. I wrote usually, because when using JQuery you most likely import the entire library in anyway.

I would always prefer installing using a package manager when possible, since:

- It is easier to install and update
- It is a standard when using frameworks like angular
- It allow to import only the actual code I need rather the entire library (Which doesn't matter much in the case on JQuery, but really useful for other libraries).